# Ordering a list of points nearest to a given point

Tags: java, point, comparator

I am trying to order a list of points by distance from a given point.

The application is to find the nearest landmarks (gps coordinates) to your current gps coordinate.

so if you take the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

        Point2D.Double point1 = new Point2D.Double(1,1);
        Point2D.Double point2 = new Point2D.Double(2,2);
        Point2D.Double point3 = new Point2D.Double(3,3);

        points.add(point1);
        points.add(point2);
        points.add(point3);

        Point2D.Double myPoint = new Point2D.Double(4,4);

    }
```

If i use a Comparator to sort the points array I will get a nice ordered list of points but how do I find which one is closer to myPoint? and what are the distances.

That should certainly answer my question, but for bonus points.. how can I limit the result of points back if give a maximum distance. eg : return an ordered list of coordinates that are no further than 100 miles.

Comment: How do you want the distance to be calculated? Euclidian distance? Manhattan distance? And this looks more like a homework question ...

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. This is all new to me. and I assure you it is not homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, some minor things:

- You should not declare the list as an `ArrayList`, but only as a `List` ( [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) )
- The same for the points: They should not be declared as `Point2D.Double`, but only als `Point2D`

Regarding the actual question: The `Point2D` class already has methods for (euclidean and other) distance computations. However, for a point storing geo coordinates, you might have to implement the distance function on your own.

In general, a comparator that compares by the distance to a given point can be implemented as in the following example:

```
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class PointsByDistanceTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();

        points.add(new Point2D.Double(1,1));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(2,2));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(3,3));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(4,4));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(5,5));
        points.add(new Point2D.Double(6,6));

        Point2D myPoint = new Point2D.Double(4,4);

        Collections.sort(points, createComparator(myPoint));

        double maxDistance = 2.0;
        int index = 0;
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            if (p.distanceSq(myPoint) > maxDistance * maxDistance)
            {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        List<Point2D> result = points.subList(0, index);
        System.out.println(
            "The closest points with distance <="+maxDistance+" are "+result);
    }

    private static Comparator<Point2D> createComparator(Point2D p)
    {
        final Point2D finalP = new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY());
        return new Comparator<Point2D>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Point2D p0, Point2D p1)
            {
                double ds0 = p0.distanceSq(finalP);
                double ds1 = p1.distanceSq(finalP);
                return Double.compare(ds0, ds1);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

The question about limiting the number of points has also been targeted in this sample: It will ony return the points that have a distance that is not greater than `maxDistance`. However, you'll still *sort* the *whole* list of points. If you want to avoid sorting the whole list, then this turns into a "K Nearest neighbors" problem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm ) where you can employ some really sophisticated data structures...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and your best practice tips. I did not want to limit the number of results back, I wanted to limit the results back according to maximum distance.

Comment: @Fuzz Sorry, I misunderstood that second part. I edited the answer with a very "pragmatic" solution: One can simply walk through the list, and see when the maximum distance is exceeded. But agin: When you have "many" points (100000 or so), and only want to look for "few" points (10 or so) that have a small distance to the referernce point, then you should use a dedicated K-Nearest-Neighbor search data structure, because the approach sketched in the answer will then be comparably inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Simple [math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)  check it.

```
     int dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b1.x - b2.x,2) - Math.pow(b1.y-b2.y,2))
```

Edit: added dot in b2x

Comment: So I could essentially, map all the distances and then sort by distance? then limit the results on the max distance I want.

Comment: pow requires 2 arguments, I think that your function should be: int dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b1.x - b2.x,2) - Math.pow(b1.y-b2.y, 2))

Comment: Three hints: **1**.: The euclidean distance is already available as a method in the `Point2D` class. **2**.: In order to compare points by their euclidean distance, you can use the *squared* distance (and save the `sqrt` computation). And **3**.: Computing x² as `pow(x,2)` is horribly inefficient. You should use `x*x` instead.

Comment: Yes your comment maybe is good but I made my point with showing some example of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using this algorithm - [Planar divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Planar_case)?

```
* Sort points according to their x-coordinates.
* Split the set of points into two equal-sized subsets by a vertical line x=xmid.
* Solve the problem recursively in the left and right subsets. This yields the 
  left-side and right-side minimum distances dLmin and dRmin, respectively.
* Find the minimal distance dLRmin among the pair of points in which one
  point lies on the left of the dividing vertical and the second point lies 
  to the right.
* The final answer is the minimum among dLmin, dRmin, and dLRmin.
```

Also you mention using GPS coordinates, if those are stored as latitude/longitude, perhaps you should use [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate distances.

Comment: Haversine isn't really needed for smaller distances; a square root of sum of powers suffices. The issue is that longitude isn't linear and so must be multiplied by cos(latitude) before you multiply by deg-to-meter constans (111244m per degree).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ordered list you can then look for the closest point by writing two lists where one is for X-coordinates and one for Y-coordinates. Then check the position of the points in list and the one with the lowest indexes is the closest point.

Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Point2D.Double>{

Point2D.Double refPoint;

public DistanceComparator(Double refPoint) {
    super();
    this.refPoint = refPoint;
}


@Override
public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
    return (refPoint.distance(o1)<refPoint.distance(o2)?-1:1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<Point2D.Double>();

        Point2D.Double point1 = new Point2D.Double(1, 1);
        Point2D.Double point2 = new Point2D.Double(2, 2);
        Point2D.Double point3 = new Point2D.Double(3, 3);

        points.add(point1);
        points.add(point2);
        points.add(point3);

        final Point2D.Double myPoint = new Point2D.Double(4, 4);

        Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(final Double o1, final Double o2) {
                double dist1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(o1.x - myPoint.x, 2) - Math.pow(o1.y - myPoint.y, 2));
                double dist2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(o2.x - myPoint.x, 2) - Math.pow(o2.y - myPoint.y, 2 ));
                return Double.compare(dist1,dist2);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: See the comment that I added in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22683547/ . In your case, additionally, the computation of the result in the comparator is flawed: When the distances are `0.3` and `0.1`, then the comparator will return `0` due to the cast to `int`. You should `return Double.compare(dist1, dist2)` instead.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I've edited the answer with your correction